# Does Firebird have an addition assignment operator?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Does Firebird have an addition assignment (`+=`) to be used in procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Firebird doesn't have compound assignment [operators](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-sqloperators).